# What is missing from jQuery in jQuery mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm building a widget library for our mobile project. The question is to use jQuery or jQuery mobile for it.

We don't need jQuery Mobile's component and page framework. Yes, it'd be great to use it, but for a variety of reasons we're rolling our own.

That said, jQuery Mobile does have enhanced touch events that we can use, which seems to be missing from jQuery at the moment (looks like that will be added in the 2.0 release). jQuery Mobile is also a smaller file than jQuery, so it makes a lot of sense to go with jQuery Mobile.

My question is why is jQuery Mobile smaller than jQuery itself? Is it missing functionality that is in jQuery? Is it just a newer rewrite so more optimized? Or is it just a lack of support for IE that makes it a thinner file?

Comment: jQuery mobile depends on jQuery, so jQuery mobile is theoretically bigger

Answer (score 6, accepted):

jQuery Mobile does not come with jQuery as far as I know. [Its download page](http://jquerymobile.com/download) shows only the JS and CSS for the mobile framework, so that would imply that the main jQuery library is a separate dependency (whose JS file you'll obtain from the [main site](http://jquery.com), naturally).

Comment: That is correct jQuery mobile depends on jQuery. So if you want to use it you would need to include jQuery 1.5 plus jQuery mobile.js

Comment: Well THAT makes sense! Did I miss that on the jQuery Mobile site? Seems that they would have made that a bit more obvious. ;)

Answer (score 2):

jQuery Mobile requires that you already reference jQuery itself.